# Responsive layouts with min-width, width%, no easy way to avoid gaps?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple responsive webpage that can run in two columns, with css for each div being

```
.half {
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
```

For wide screens each div column gets half the width, for narrower screens the columns compress until they reach 300px, and then they wrap.  Basically works OK.

However, when the screen is 400px wide (say) the columns are still compressed to 300px.  (Because half of  400px is 200px, so min-width of 300px takes priority.  But in this case I would want it to be the full 400px as there are no other columns to its right.)

Is there a easy way to stop that?

There are new flex-box options, but I need to run on the public web, lots of browsers and phones.  Something that polishes for newer and works for older is OK.  I do not want to add JavaScript just to do this.

I think that the answer is a simple NO, not possible.  But I would appreciate confirmation that I have not missed something.

(There are a number of similar questions already but none that I could find that address this simple case specifically.)

(Edited to address confusion in comments.)

Comment: "However, when the screen is 400px wide (say) the columns are still compressed to 300px." huh?

Comment: It looks like you have multiple divs [like this example](https://jsbin.com/ramise/edit?html,css,output) and they wrap on narrow screens. **You need to add a proper example** in the question that recreates what you are seeing. Include the HTML.

Comment: Also, any reason not to use 50% width? Using `box-sizing: border-box` you can incorporate the padding and borders into the width calculation and create pseudo-margins with borders. [Like this example](https://jsbin.com/bomoki/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are wanting to implement a `media-query` to specify new rules once a window is less than a specific width. Therefore, you could do something like:

```
// Override styles for elements once the element is less than a specified width
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    // If window is less than 400px, apply new styles. ie: width takes full width
    .half {              
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Which will make the `.half` class 100% width once the device/window is 400px or less.

Example of `media-query` provided by [misterManSam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2930477/mistermansam): [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/bomoki/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: That's what I assume they need +1, you might as well [add this example I already made](https://jsbin.com/bomoki/edit?html,css,output) as a snippet to your answer.

Comment: @misterManSam's trick Seems to work OK in modern browsers.  Although I used "all" instead of "only screen", any reason for the latter?    

**Question**: How do older browsers treat the unexpected @media?  Do they figure out how to ignore the entire clause with its different syntax?

Comment: @aberglas - [`@media` is incredibly well supported, including IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries). In the crazy rare case that it is not supported (these days only IE8 will be a problem), the browser will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need like this:

```
.half {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;/*define max-width as you wish*/
  float: left;
}
```